# How to add a click listener to polymer custom element's child?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to add a click listener to one of the buttons inside a custom element in the **"created"** life cycle callback (even tried **"ready"** callback with same result).

I am thrown with the error "button element is undefined/null".

---

**Note:**

a. I cannot add a click listener for the whole custom component like this.

```
   listeners: {
        'click': '_onClick'
    },
```

I just need to add a listener to the button. How to get this simple thing? Sorry I am sounding naive.

b. Cannot do inline script because of CSP restriction

```
<paper-button id='saveBtn' on-click="handleClick">
     Save
</paper-button>
```

---

**Error Msg:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>
> Polymer.created @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:10596Polymer.Base._addFeature._invokeBehavior
>   @ elements-imports.csp.js:267Polymer.Base._addFeature._doBehavior @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:262Polymer.Base.createdCallback @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:97Polymer.Base._addFeature.instanceTemplate @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:535Polymer.Base._addFeature._stampTemplate @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:531Polymer.Base._addFeature._initFeatures @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:4627Polymer.attached @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:5612Polymer.Base._addFeature._invokeBehavior @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:267Polymer.Base._addFeature._doBehavior @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:262Polymer.Base.attachedCallback @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:102Polymer.Base._addFeature.attachedCallback @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:603Polymer.Base._addFeature._readySelf @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:591(anonymous function) @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:5554Polymer.ImportStatus._importsLoaded @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:5553(anonymous function) @
>   elements-imports.csp.js:5564checkDone @
>   webcomponents-lite.js:968watchImportsLoad @
>   webcomponents-lite.js:990(anonymous function) @
>   webcomponents-lite.js:939whenDocumentReady @
>   webcomponents-lite.js:957checkReady @ webcomponents-lite.js:952

---

**Custom Element:**

```
<dom-module id="my-form">
    <template>
        <div>
            <paper-input id="inputName" label="Name" required error-message="Required Input"> Name </paper-input>
            <paper-input id="inputServer" label="Server URL" required error-message="Required Input"> Server </paper-input>
            <paper-input id="inputUsername" label="Username" required error-message="Required Input">Username</paper-input>
            <paper-input id="inputPassword" label="Password" type="password" required error-message="Required Input" value="">Password</paper-input>
            <div class="rows layout horizontal right-justified certificate">
                <paper-button id='cancelBtn' tabindex="0">Cancel</paper-button>
                <paper-button id='saveBtn' tabindex="0">Save</paper-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
Polymer({

    is: 'my-form',

    created: function() {
        var saveBtn = document.querySelector('#saveBtn');
        saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('inputName').validate();
            document.getElementById('inputServer').validate();
            document.getElementById('inputUsername').validate();
            document.getElementById('inputPassword').validate();
        });
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `on-click="handleClick"`

Is not inline code, it's just an attribute, so it works just fine under CSP.

> created()

Is too early, your elements are not made yet.

> ready()

Your elements are made at this point, but they are not necessarily in `document`, so using `document.querySelector` (or `document.getElement*`) is a bad idea.

However, Polymer provides a map of elements in your template by id as a property called `$`, so you can write `var saveBtn = this.$.saveBtn` (but you should use `on-click` instead).

Comment: Thank you Scott. I take your advice about on-click. But just curious about "attached" callback. Also I found a way to add a button listener in the JS. listeners: {
        'saveBtn.tap': 'saveBtnListener'
    }, .............   saveBtnListener: function(e) { ....... }. It actually worked. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#event-listeners

Comment: What is your question about `attached` callback? You mean as an alternative to `ready`? Is has the same problem. Where ShadowDOM is native these elements are _never in document_.

Comment: Thank you Scott. Yes my question was how about using "attached".